# Vector input in FOR loop causing run-time error - Debugging times out

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, runtime-error, c++14

I am trying to debug my C++ program for stdin as

```
2 1 /newline/
4
```

Output of debugger (onlinegdb):-
While the second line was getting read for another set of inputs provided by question; this time, the vector arr is not showing the output 4 
set args 
Reading symbols from /home/a.out...done.
(gdb) continue
The program is not being run.
(gdb) run

```
Starting program: /home/a.out </home/input.txt                                
2 1  

P.S. The program successfully compiles and runs for user provided input

3 2
3
4
```

P.S. SO, WHY IS THE FIRST FOR LOOP IN THE PROGRAM NOT EXECUTING CORRECTLY?

SOURCE CODE-

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int m;
    cin>>m;
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    cout<<m<<" "<<t<<"\n";
    int sum=0;
    vector<int> arr(t);
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        cin>>arr[i];                //arr[i]=k digit nos
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" "; 
    int comb(int a, int b);         //6,2

    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        if(m==arr[i]){
            cout<<m<<" a "<<9*pow(10,m-1)<<"\n";
        }
        if(m>arr[i]){
            cout<<m<<" b "<<9*pow(10,m-1)<<"\n";
        } 
        if(m<arr[i]){
            /*if(m==arr[i]-1){
            cout<<m<<" c "<<9*pow(10,arr[i]-1)-9<<"\n";  
            }
            else{*/
            sum=pow(10,arr[i])-1;
            for(int j=arr[i]-1;j>m;j++)
                sum=sum-comb(arr[i],j)*pow(9,arr[i]-j+1);
            cout<<" d "<<sum<<"\n";
            //}
        }
    }
    //for m upto 10^4, k<=10^5; else k=10^5
    return 0;
}
int comb(int a, int b) {      //6,2
        int j=1;
        int s=a;
        for(int k=a-1;k>b;k--)     //5,4,3
            s=s*k;
        for(int l=1;l<=b;l++)
            s=s/l;
        return s;
    }
    //It is a problem involving displaying number of integers with no digit //repeating more than m (=2 here) times for t(=1) inputs with each input //being a arr[i] (=4) digit number.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that is the problem but... is a problem

Look at the case `if (m<arr[i])` (that is your case, if I understand correctly, because `t` is 1; the only valid `arr[i]` is `arr[0]` that is 4 and is greather than `m` that is 2).

Your actual code is

```
        for(int j=arr[i]-1;j>m;j++)
            sum=sum-comb(arr[i],j)*pow(9,arr[i]-j+1);
```

Remembering that `arr[i]` is `arr[0]` that is 4, and `m == 2`, you code become

```
        for ( int j = 3 ; j > 2 ; j++ )
           sum -= comb(4, j) * pow(9, 5 - j);
```

So `j` start from 3 and is *incremented* until `j > 2`; but if `j` start from 3 and is incremented is ever greater that 2.

I suppose your code should *decrement* `j`; something like

```
        for ( auto j = arr[i] - 1 ; j > m ; ++j )
            sum -= comb(arr[i], j) * pow(9, arr[i]-j+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

@max66 has pointed out why your program is stuck in loop.

Let me explain why vector arr is not showing the output 4.

I think your input is reading it properly. But gdb hasn't printed it yet. Since output is buffered, its not necessary that it will be printed on screen at the same time you `cout`. 
If you want to do so, then you should flush the output.

```
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    cout<<arr[i]<<" "<<flush;
```